# Pagination for very long string Django 1.11 (Python 3.6)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-pagination

I'm trying to create my own blog site which might contain a very long story (from one field in database). I successfully create pagination for list of records (for the list of stories) on my other views and tried to experiment from the Django documentation. What I did is create an array from the very long string so django pagination can count it.

"views.py"

```
def post_detail(request, slug=None):  #retrieve
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

words_list = instance.content.split()
paginator = Paginator(words_list, 500)  # Show 25 contacts per page

page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    words = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    words = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    words = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

if instance.draft or instance.publish > timezone.now().date():
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
share_string = urlquote_plus(instance.content)
context = {
    "title": instance.title,
    "instance": instance,
    "share_string": share_string,
    "word_content": words,
}

return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

I successfully created it but as a list of words from top to bottom instead of paragraph format which doesn't look good at all.

"post_detail.html"

```
{% for word_con in word_content %}
            <p class="text-justify">{{ word_con }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to concatinate it using this:

```
{% for word_con in word_content %}
            <p class="text-justify">{{ ' '.join(word_con) }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

but gets an error.

Comment: I want to make something like this: https://pagely.com/blog/2015/03/wordpress-auto-post-pagination/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround to make this work. This is not the best resolution but it works for me.

```
def post_detail(request, slug=None):  #retrieve
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

#Detect the breaklines from DB and split the paragraphs using it
tempInstance = instance.content
PaginatedInstance = tempInstance.split("\r\n\r\n")

paginator = Paginator(PaginatedInstance, 5)  #set how many paragraph to show per page

page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

try:
    Paginated = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    Paginated = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    Paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    "Paginated": Paginated,  #will use this to display the story instead of instance (divided string by paragraph)
}

return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

Instead of counting all the characters, I decided to split the string per paragraph and saved it in an array and that is the one that I paginated on the template file

```
{% for paginatedText in Paginated %}
        {{ paginatedText }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not doing in a right way. Instead of using Pagination for contents, you can use Ajax for loading more content, load more button will load the content of your post.

The flow of content will be like this, first load 500 character then after user presses load more button, then you do an ajax call and bring next 500 character and append to previous content. And so on.

Comment: I'll try it. But is it advisable to do it that way instead of doing pagination since the content might reach like 50 pages if it will be done in a document file?

Comment: As you have mentioned in your question, that you need pagination of content for your blog right? Then according to me you should do this by loading your content gradually 500 character by 500 character. If you think that your content is much as larger that it fits in 50 pages, then you can increase your character (upto 1500 characters) after one or more load more ajax request. If you want to know how to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Can you please give an example that i can apply in django?